# Can an ion thruster work without applied voltage?

Tags: rocket-science, propulsion, ions

In this image, power is used to apply voltage to the charged grids.
But if no voltage is applied, would ions still be accelerated by Coulomb forces to create thrust? If not, why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Coulomb forces to create thrust? If not, why?

While the voltage is applied, the protons are being pulled to the right and the electrons to the left. This keeps the interior part at some internal level of charge separation as the electrons and protons move apart. I suspect the overall charge is close to neutral, although I don't know enough about the injected electrons and how fast they move back onto the left side. In any event, the system will be net negative on the left and net positive on the right as things are pulled apart by the voltage.

Now imagine what would happen if you turned it off. In that case there is no longer anything pulling the electrons and ions apart. Opposite charges attract, so those highly mobile electrons will quickly connect to the ions, turning them back into normal atoms. And so in a very very quick period, you no longer have electrons and ions, you have a dilute neutral gas.

So no, no leftover Coulomb forces to keep things going. There might be a slight excess of electrons, so a tiny effect, but my feeling is this all happens so quickly that the overall internal charge is going to be very close to neutral.

Comment: But protons and electrons would be in separate grids, they couldn't connect with each other.

Comment: Btw the plasma in my example would only have ions. Still no thrust?

Comment: The example you show has protons and electrons in the same area. With no voltage on the system, there is nothing stopping them from reconnecting. There's really no way to build it anyway else, you need *something* pulling them apart.

Answer (score 2):

> In this image, power is used to apply voltage to the charged grids.

The voltage is applied in order to charge the grids. It is the act of applying the voltage which gives the grids their charge.

> But if no voltage is applied, would ions still be accelerated by Coulomb forces to create thrust? If not, why?

If no voltage were applied then the grids would not be charged. Without charged grids there would be no Coulomb forces and no ion acceleration.

Furthermore, without the charged grid there would be nothing to separate the positive charges from the negative charges in the plasma. The plasma is overall neutral, so it will not have an overall self-force.

Comment: I think you missed his question: he's saying if you have this chamber filled with ions, would their own electrostatic repulsion led to them being blown out the right side to produce thrust.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz exactly

Comment: OK, I added a paragraph for that.

Comment: The plasma in my example would only have ions

Comment: @Beom ok, your example has a 100% ionization fraction. My answer doesn't depend on the ionization fraction

Comment: @Beom How do you propose to create a cloud of ions without associated electrons?